# How could I extend this result to a case where the matrices were not of full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

I'm reading this paper by [Bhatia, Jain and Lim](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01504.pdf) and on page 6 theorem 2, they state

$$
\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})} = \max_{X>0} \{ |\operatorname{tr} X|: A\geq XB^{-1}X^{*} \}
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices.

Is there a way to relax this in the case that $A$ and $B$ are instead PSD and not of full rank? I don't think I can carry out the similar steps as they do in the proof since $B$ may not necessarily be invertible now.

---

Someone told me that this is doable since $A$ is PD on the same subspace as $B$ because if $A$ is positive where $B$ is zero, then the scale of $X$ in that direction can be infinite. If $B$ is positive where $A$ is zero, then $X$ is zero in that direction, so the max is over the subspace.

I don't quite follow this -- can someone explain why this is the case? Also doesn't it matter that $X$ can be infinite in some direction?

Comment: Relax the assumption of PD to PSD. And they proved the above on that same page.

Comment: Someone told me I could just restrict this to the subspace where $A$ and $B$ were PD. I don't know why if $A$ were PD on a subspace, then so would $B$ and vice versa. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to relax the condition $A \geq XB^{-1}X^*$ to the case when $B$ is not full-rank is transforming it to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & X\\
X^* & B
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0,
$$
which is equivalent by standard results on Schur complements (when $A \geq 0$). So this change would give you a candidate statement that is valid also for PSD matrices. Then proving it is another question --- but it looks like the kind of thing that can be proved using a continuity argument.

Comment: Continuity argument in which way? With respect to what?

Comment: @Glassjawed Change $A$ and $B$ to $A+\varepsilon I$ and $B+\varepsilon I$, and let $\varepsilon \to 0$. Then clearly the LHS is continuous; the RHS is less clear, at least to me, but I hope something can be said.

Comment: LHS and RHS refer to the $\sqrt{tr(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})}$ and $\max_{X>0} \{ \left|tr X\right|: A\geq XB^{-1}X^{*} \}$?

Comment: @Glassjawed Yes.

Comment: Hmm...yeah do you perhaps have a few minutes to chat privately? I'm thinking maybe I could use the pseudoinverse $(B'B)^{-1}$ instead of $B^{-1}$ and get a result. But I'm also wondering if the argument that A and B are PD on the same subpsace makes sense to you as well.

Comment: @Glassjawed No, sorry, I do not have much time right now and I prefer to interact only through MO (not even in chat). But anyway the argument that A and B are PD on the same subspace looks suspicious to me, thinking about the involved changes of bases.

Comment: Yeah, I think the RHS would have been continuous (continuity of the trace, max of cts function is continuous) if not for the absolute value sign. Is that what you were thinking as well?

Comment: @Glassjawed No. Something like the $1\times 1$ case with $A=1$, $B \to 0$, which seems problematic.

Comment: Okay. It looks like they proved the relaxed condition in the paper right before (18). Now the question is how to avoid inverting $B^{-1}$ for the rest of the proof.